# Scala - String to Url

Tags: java, scala, url

My `Scala` class requires a URL.  I could use a `String` class, but I'd like Java's built in URL validation.  What's the best way to allow it to take either a Java Url class, or a String, and, if a String, turn it into a Java Url?

Answer (score 7):

You can create an implicit conversion from `String` to `URL` and accept only `URL` (this is what you want anyway). The `implicit def` might be in the companion class or in a helper class/trait (trait in the cake pattern). Something like this:

```
implicit def `string to url`(s: String) = new URL(s)
```

Usage:

```
import the.helper.Container._
//or implement the Helper trait containing the implicit def
val url: URL = "http://google.com"
```

The drawback is, exceptions might arrive from unexpected places (any might require a further `import`).

A less implicit approach would be "adding" a `toURL` method to `String`, like this:

```
object Helpers {
  implicit class String2URL(s: String) {
    def toURL = new URL(s)
  }
}
```

Usage of this would look like this:

```
import Helpers._
val aUrl = "http://google.com".toURL
```

Comparison to @m-z's answer: you can combine multiple parameters this way without explosion of combination of different parameters, while for that answer it will exponential (though for small exponents, like in this case `1`, that is perfectly fine). @m-z's answer is not reusable, if you need another class, you have to create it again. It works on the library side, so the lib users get a nice documentation, guide how to use it, mine would just work with "magic" and/or small user help (like `import` of the method, `toURL` conversion method call). I would choose @m-z's solution for small combinations too, especially with the adjustment of `Option` or `Try`. But if you need to overload multiple parameters, I think my solution works better. It really depends on your use case. (You can wrap mine with `Try` too if there might be cases where the passed url is not valid.)

Answer (score 5):

You could use an overloaded constructor or `apply` method:

```
class A(id: Int, url: URL) {
    def this(id: Int, url: String) = this(id, new URL(url))
}
```

Or

```
case class A(id: Int, url: URL)

object A {
    def apply(id: Int, url: String): A = new A(id, new URL(url))
}
```

Comment: IMHO it's better to have an `Option[A]` or `Try[A]` for the apply method because `new URL` may fail.